# git pull displays "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/xxxx" and hangs up

Tags: git

I created a branch called `6796`, then I pushed it to remote, checked it out on another machine, made other edits, pushed it, then merged it with `master`, and deleted it locally and remotely on the other machine (`git push :6796`). Now, when I run `git pull`:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/6796
user@host:~/path/to/repo$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

but `git pull origin master` works normally. It seems to me that there is a `6796` reference somewhere... how to resolve this?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

There are probably some commands to resolve it, but I would start by looking in your `.git/config` file for references to that branch, and removing them.

Comment: Thank you! I had this line in .git/config:

`[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/6796:refs/remotes/origin/6796`

I guess this line is there because I deleted the remote branch and pruned it from another server; so on that server git knew about the deletion, and removed the line in .git/config, but here git was not notified about the deletion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the `prune` option supplied by @jweyrich is good to "refresh" the origin status

Comment: look for .gitconfig on your root directory

Answer (score 28):

You also have to delete the local branch:

```
git branch -d 6796
```

Another way is to prune all stale branches from your local repository. This will delete all local branches that already have been removed from the remote:

```
git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

Comment: that's good way to do it (git remote prune). Is it possible that git will remove something that still exists on remote? I mean is this command dangerous or it only prunes branches that are already deleted from remote

Comment: @NickSoft, quoting the [official documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html): `Deletes all stale tracking branches under <name>. These stale branches have already been removed from
       the remote repository referenced by <name>, but are still locally available in "remotes/<name>".

       With --dry-run option, report what branches will be pruned, but do no actually prune them.`

Answer (score 12):

In my case, it was the "Lightweight checkout" checkbox that was checked by default, while, as it happens, I needed it unchecked. Can you spot it?

[image]

I didn't investigate why did it cause such an abrupt error, but since it blocked my Jenkins jobs for a couple of hours, I felt it's worth sharing on top of the other answers here.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. But in my case it was due to my branch's name. The branch's name automatically set in my GitHub repo as main instead of master.

```
git pull origin master
```

(did not work).

I confirmed in GitHub if the name of the branch was actually master and found the the actual name was main. so the commands below worked for me.

```
git pull origin main
```

Comment: I can confirm this. The first answer here has more information about transitioning from master to main:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249491/difference-between-main-branch-and-master-branch-in-github

Comment: What a crap show that github did with this master/main change... I was stuck on this issue for half an hour 

Answer (score 4):

This error could be thrown in the following situation as well.

You want to checkout branch called `feature` from remote repository but the error is thrown because you already have branch called `feature/<feature_name>` in your local repository.

Simply checkout the `feature` branch under a different name:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <remote>/feature
```

Answer (score 4):

To pull a remote branch locally, I do the following:

> `git checkout -b branchname`
>   // creates a local branch with the same name and checks out on it
>
> `git pull origin branchname`    // pulls the remote one onto your local one

The only time I did this and it didn't work, I deleted the repo, cloned it again and repeated the above 2 steps; it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar issue when I tried to commit to a newly created repo with a **"."** in it's name.  I've seen several others have different issues with putting a "." in the repo name.

I just re-created the repo and

```
replaced "." with "-"
```

There may be other ways to resolve this, but this was a quick fix for me since it was a new repo.

Comment: What do you mean by name?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when I tried to get a pull with a single quote  '  in it's name.

I had to escape the pull request name:

```
git pull https://github.com/foo/bar namewithsingle"'"quote
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same error. Problem was that branch was deleted, released. But in PhpStorm I still could see it in remote branches. I could checkout as local branch. And then doing git pull was giving this error.

So need to check if this brnach really exists remotely.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happenned for the master branch. Later found that my access to the project was accidentally revoked by the project manager. To cross-check, I visited the review site and couldn't see any commits of the said branch and others for that project.