# Create a Git Repo through SSH and Cloning it Locally

Tags: git, ssh

I have a website on a shared host which support git. Working with FTP is getting too difficult so I am planning to use git in my workflow. I just know basic push, pull, commit commands. I would like to set-up git but not being able to work it out. Here is what I tried till now.

```
ssh user@host
cd ~/mysitedirectory/html
git init
```

and it says git repo initialised. On my local computer, I did this

```
cd my/local/path
git init
git remote add origin ssh://user@host:/chroot/somedir/mysiteditectory/html/.git
git pull origin master
```

And it asks for password, which I provide. Then it throws following error.

fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
***-iMac:PB_Source ***$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I am trying it from last 2-3 hours. Can't find solution. Please guide me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but usually with this setup you'd have a bare repository located on your server, outside the web root created with git init --bare. The git homepage has a good book with instructions about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull displays "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/xxxx" and hangs up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930147/git-pull-displays-fatal-couldnt-find-remote-ref-refs-heads-xxxx-and-hangs-up)

Comment: I suggest using `git clone` instead of this longer sequence of commands.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation I found that removing the slash at the beggining of the path, solved the issue. But the syntax was not the same. When using the colon you do not add ssh:// I'd say, so:

`git remote add origin user@host:chroot/somedir/mysiteditectory/html/.git`

OR

`git remote add origin ssh://user@host/chroot/somedir/mysitedirectory/html/.git`