# main and master are entirely different commit histories. I am adding a new repository to my github

Tags: git, github

I am a newbie to git, i just decided to put all of my projects up on github. This is what i did:

1. Went to my project directory
2. Went to my github profile, created a new repository. Added a README file and did commit.
3. On my command line did "git init" and "git add ."
4. "git commit -m 'source code'" to commit all of my source code in the repo
5. git remote add origin
6. git remote -v
7. And finally "git push origin master" to push the complete source code.

But for some reason, the commit i performed went to a branch called "main" which i never created. The README file i initially created is in the "master" branch. And when i went to the "compare and pull request" option, it showed this message:

> > There isn’t anything to compare.
>
> main and master are entirely different commit histories.

Can someone please help me with this? What i want to do is add a new repository and put all of my source code in that repository along with a README file. I am not experienced with github

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between Main Branch and Master Branch in Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249491/difference-between-main-branch-and-master-branch-in-github) 
**tl;dr** Github by default creates a `main` branch instead of a `master` branch for new repositories. If you push to a `master` on one of those you simply create a new (unrelated) branch in that repository).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I understood that they are gonna change the default branch to main instead of master. But the issue becomes, i am unable to merge these two. My first commit was on "merge" branch (README) and than my second commit automatically went to "main". How do i merge these two??

Comment: [Explanation for the “entirely different” error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23350970/1725151)

Answer (score 1):

After you create a new repo on github, it might list the steps you need to initialize a repo which you'd be able to copy paste. If it's not there, try the following:

```
cd project-dir
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit message"
git remote add origin ssh://git@link_to_your_github_repo
git push -u origin master
```

This sequence of commands should push everything in your project-dir to the master branch of your new github repo.

**PS.**

If you're not starting from scratch with a clean repo, you could follow the steps discussed in [There isn't anything to compare. Nothing to compare, branches are entirely different commit histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe)

Comment: I did exactly that. My first commit was on "merge" branch (README) which i did through the website and than my second commit automatically went to "main" even though i gave :git push origin master command. And now it won't let me merge these two

Comment: My proposal above would require starting from a clean slate, but try the solution discussed in the article below. It details how to merge two branches in a state like yours. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with me but how I solved it was that I created the remote repository without adding the README.md file, went to my terminal;

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git remote add origin url_for_repo
git push -u origin master
```

You can then add your README.md file on your remote repository after pushing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before.

It's because you are in a master branch, you want to change the default branch back to main. You can check what branch you are in using the command

```
git branch
```

So the steps you want to do in the terminal are as follows.

```
git init 
git add .
git status <to see all the files you want to commit>
git  commit -m "Your message"
git branch -M main #THIS WILL SET YOUR BRANCH TO MAIN
git remote add origin <git@github.com:Username/YourRepoName.git>
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no history of your commits, so you need to commit history first.

```
git fetch main
git checkout master
git rebase origin/main
```

This will apply your commit on top of the latest changes from main branch, then conflict may occur resolve it and stage the commit with add then continue and push

```
git add . 
git rebase --continue
git push origin master --force
```