# Difference between "git push origin master" and "git push origin main instead"

Tags: git

I worked on php Project and i want to upload into "github" I am new in Github, I want to know that what is difference between "git push origin master" and "git push origin main" ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: no difference. "master" and "main" are branch names. It can be "foo", "soup" or anything else.

Comment: What do you mean "the difference"? These are variable names. What's the difference between variable `foo` and variable `bar`? Different identifiers, that's all.

Comment: these are not a variable names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "git push main" work on GitHub when "git push master" does not? Also what is difference between "Main branch" and "Master branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249491/why-does-git-push-main-work-on-github-when-git-push-master-does-not-also-wh)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski "*these are not a variable names*"? What was that?

Comment: Plain literal string being git's argument representing name of the branch to operate on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the names of branches on a repository on Git.

The master branch is the main branch on the code repository and now it is famous as the Main branch in Git.

So when you add changes to your repository You can use `git push origin master` or `git push origin main` in your repository.

If suppose you have name dev as branch name then you need to use that name like :

```
git push origin dev
```

Answer (score 2):

`git push origin master` is pushing the code to the master branch.
`git push origin main` is pushing the code to the main branch.

Answer (score 2):

Origin and Master are two different terminologies used when working and managing the git projects.

**Origin** is the name used for the remote repository.

**Master / Main** is the name of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have answered before: `main` or `master` is just name of a branch. It can have an arbitrary name and which one is to be considered the "main" branch is up to convention.

Earlier versions of git used `master` so a lot of older repositories use this name. In recent times, `main` is favored.

It's really up to the individual project which branch to use.

There are also [political issues](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-53050955) involved. From a practical point of view, `main` is shorter by two letters so it saves some typing.