# Online files not synchronised with local files

Tags: gitlab

I wrote `git ls-remote c-negation` to retrieve the branches in my repository, which results in:

`110bf702ee2653430aea50948dfb26ef0d1785da  HEAD 4bff9fa1736ae5a5dc1f3becd4fd941720f04f83    refs/heads/hfix 739851a9d23553a5af23079c2e792952a9a0d93f    refs/heads/master 9e1c1b066db9ae97025e985eace17fa5adac1b7d    refs/heads/paper 110bf702ee2653430aea50948dfb26ef0d1785da    refs/heads/t21 9e39cb92d8e48ff8b2d8bcea7341d0fc01df96ed    refs/heads/t21-techrpt 739851a9d23553a5af23079c2e792952a9a0d93f    refs/remotes/origin/HEAD be6205b5e8329939027a09456fade70f11a834a5    refs/remotes/origin/hfix 739851a9d23553a5af23079c2e792952a9a0d93f    refs/remotes/origin/master 9e1c1b066db9ae97025e985eace17fa5adac1b7d    refs/remotes/origin/paper fc23cecde3706e4a4b539de57e31865ecf4fde3e    refs/remotes/origin/t21 0c527bc69858161bbe98d94bbdb8cffe653cc796    refs/remotes/origin/weak-seq 3661bc75f3d312a2527f9ace87a31efcd80a2224    refs/stash`

However, when I write `git checkout t21-techrpt` and check the file `c-negation` on my computer, it does not list all the files which are on the online repository. I have tried pulling and fetching and this doesn't make a difference: I still can't see the files on the online repository in the branch `t21-techrpt`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using the new [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command:

```
git fetch
git switch t21-techrpt
```

If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`, or here `origin`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:

```
git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

Answer (score -1):

The result of the command `ls-remote` depends on the argument. It works with directories - lists local git repository, and with remote aliases - lists "online" repositories.

1. When `c-negation` is your project directory.

Branch `t21-techrpt` present as a local branch - `refs/heads/t21-techrpt`, but it's not present as a remote one. It should be listed as `refs/remotes/origin/t21-techrpt`.

If you want to update your local branch with remote changes. Just pull it:

```
git pull origin t21-techrpt
```

2. When `c-negation` is listed in `git remote -v` as alias.

The command should be like that:

```
git pull c-negation t21-techrpt
```

Comment: ``git pull c-negation t21-techrpt`` produces ``fatal: Couldn't find remote ref t21-techrpt`` and ``fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly``.

Comment: So if the branch `t21-teckrpt` exists in remote `c-nagation` there is the same issue solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930399/6640136

Comment: But that question is about branches which you have created. I didn't create the branch ``t21-techrpt``, someone else did.

Comment: So you haven't answered my question at all

Comment: Let's go the full path.

Branch `t21-techrpt` isn't present in local ones:
```
git branch
```

The remote repository URL with alias `<remote-alias>` is the same as you expect:
```
git remote -v
```

And the branch `t21-techrpt` is present in remote repository as `<commit-sha> /refs/heads/t21-techrpt`:
```
git ls-remote <remote-alias>
```

Comment: So using commands listed below should switch your project to the latest remote version.
```
git fetch <remote-alias> t21-techrpt
git checkout t21-techrpt
```

But `git fetch <remote-alias> t21-techrpt` failed with `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref t21-techrpt` and `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` usually tells about remote branch you are looking for doesn't exist.

It can be just a misprint in branch name, remote alias or remote URL.

Comment: If they are correct means only the remote branch doesn't exist. You can check it by cloning project to another directory:
```
git clone <repo-url> <dirname>
cd dirname
git branch -r
```

Comment: It does exist. I have seen it by going on the gitlab website, and my colleagues can access it.